# more simpler way to filter two optional condition

Tags: scala

Say there is a function with two optional parameters represent two different condition to filter.

```
def judge(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) {
  // here filter according the values of `a` and `b` if are set (not empty)
  // if `a` or `b` is empty, then ignore. 
  // And if `a` and `b` both are empty, then filtering get nothing.
  val objs: List[SomeObject] = ...

  if (!(a.isEmpty) || !(b.isEmpty)) {
    objs.filter { obj =>
      a.map(_ == obj.a).getOrElse(true) && b.map(_ == obj.b).getOrElse(true)
    }
  } else {
    List[SomeObject]()
  }
}
```

It seems works, but I think the way is a little verbose. Is there another simpler way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make two changes.

**1**. `!(a.isEmpty) || !(b.isEmpty)` is difficult to read and requires you (or at least me) to scrutinize the logic a little more to verify what it's actually doing.

`(a.nonEmpty || b.nonEmpty)` would be more expressive and logically equivalent.

**2**. I think it would be more idiomatic to use `forall` within the `filter`.

For example:

```
a.forall(_ == obj.a)
```

would be the same as:

```
a.map(_ == obj.a).getOrElse(true)
```

And I think it's more clear as to what it does. It's saying *for all elements contained in `a`, they must be equal to `obj.a`*. If `a` is empty, then by default all of it's elements are equal to `obj.a` (because it doesn't have any, so we can say anything about them and it will be true).

Now your function could look more like this:

```
def judge(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): List[SomeObject] = {
  val objs = ...

  if (a.nonEmpty || b.nonEmpty) {
    objs.filter { obj =>
      a.forall(_ == obj.a) && b.forall(_ == obj.b)
    }
  } else Nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks fine to me except the filter.  Consider:

```
objs filter { obj =>
  ( a.isEmpty || a.get == obj.a ) && ( b.isEmpty || b.get == obj.b )
}
```

In cases like these where you want the behavior in the "None" case to "mix in" with the behavior for the "Some" case, map is kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to test whether each parameter is a `Some` over and over for each object in the list -- you only need to do that once.  `map` each argument to a function that performs the test, and then `flatten` those into a list of filter functions.  Then if there were filters, `reduce` them into a single filter and apply it to the list:

```
def judge(optA: Option[Int], optB: Option[Int]) = {
  val foos = List(Foo(1,2), Foo(3,4))
  val filters = List(
    optA map (a => (foo: Foo) => foo.a == a),
    optB map (b => (foo: Foo) => foo.b == b)
  ).flatten
  if (filters.isEmpty) foos else foos filter filters.reduce{
    (f1, f2) => (foo: Foo) => f1(foo) && f2(foo)
  }
}
```

Using a `Vector` to hold the objects would improve performance, both by dramatically reducing the number of objects allocated and by avoiding the implicit `reverse` that would be done after filtering a `List`.